# How to understand the definition of limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, intuition

> **Definition 1:** Let $f(x)$ be defined on an interval that contains $x=a$. Then we say that, $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$$
>   if for every number $\epsilon$ there is some number $\lambda$ such that
>   $$|f(x) - L|<\epsilon \text{ whenever    } 0<|x-a|<\lambda.$$

I understand what this theorem is trying to tell me in terms of mathematical conditions. I also understand the vertical and horizontal line test. The range mapped by the domain has to be within something called 'the pink area', but I still don't see the big picture of it or I don't see the importance of that so called 'pink area'. What does close enough mean?. I have taken several calculus classes and still don't understand a single thing about it.

[image: pinkarea]

What was the original problem that led to this problem?

Comment: This "pink area" is not a phrase I've heard before. Is it related to some specific figure?

Comment: @Arthur it refers to the diagram the OP posted

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617703/trying-to-understand-delta-epsilon-interpretation-of-limits?rq=1 help? (@MichaelMcGovern the diagram was added in response to @Arthur's comment!)

Comment: Here's a video that I'd recommend: https://youtu.be/mb2kLe86EZA Dr. Censor spends an hour discussing about the definition and its motivation

Comment: It is not a theorem, it is a definition.

Comment: I think the "sad" comments are expressing genuine sympathy, not criticism. It's perfectly understandable to struggle with this definition, which is often not explained clearly. Here's an attempt: Do you want $f(x)$ to be within $.001$ of $L$? Ok, I can make that happen by finding a sufficiently small value of $\delta$ and requiring that $x$ is within $\delta$ of $a$. No matter how much accuracy you demand (that is, no matter how small of an $\epsilon$ you give me), I can always find my $\delta$ to satisfy your demand.

Answer (score 5):

> I have taken several calculus classes and still don't understand a
>   single thing about it.

That's sad. Here's a related kind of example that may help.

Suppose you would like to calculate the square root $x$ of $2$. If all you need is an answer within $1$ of the correct answer, then using any value between $x=1$ and $1.5$ will do, since $1^2 \le 2  \le 1.5^2$. If you need an answer that's within $0.1$ of the true value, you will need a tighter inequality on $x$. If you need two decimal place accuracy you will have to restrict $x$ to an even smaller interval. But you can always manage that. If you specify in advance the accuracy you require (typically, that will be some small number traditionally named "$\epsilon$") then it is possible to restrict the value of $x$ to an interval *small enough* to guarantee that any $x$ in that interval, when squared, will be a *good enough* approximation - that is, within $\epsilon$ of the true value. We usually use $\delta$ to specify an amount that $x$ can differ from the true value and still guarantee a square withing $\epsilon$ of $2$. It's pretty clear that the smaller $\epsilon$ you start with the smaller $\delta$ will have to be. But you can always find such a $\delta$. That's what it means for the squaring function to be continuous.

Perhaps think of yourself as a consultant asked by a client for a number whose square is close to $2$. To help him out, you ask first "how close to $2$ must the square be?". Until he gives you a value, you can't give him a number. Once he specifies his tolerance, you go back to your desk and compute, and tell him he can use any number between $a$ and $b$ and he'll be safe. Of course you can't find $a$ and $b$ until you know his requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your outlined text is not a theorem, but a **definition**.

As Ethan Bolker has said, it is **sad** that after so many attempts you "still understand a single thing about it".

The basic notion is **continuity**. A function $f$ is *continuous* at a point $a\in{\rm dom}(f)$  if inputting an $x$ sufficiently near  $a$ into $f$ results in a value $f(x)\approx f(a)$. Of course this intuitive idea has to be expanded into a clear mathematical definition. A simple idea would be to require that $|f(x)-f(a)|\leq |x-a|$, i.e., that the output error is at most as large as the input error. We would also be content with $|f(x)-f(a)|\leq C\,|x-a|$ with a certain constant $C$, say $C=20$. It has turned out that a such so-called *Lipschitz condition* is not sufficient to capture, e.g., the continuity of $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ $(x\geq0)$ at $a=0$, and so we were led to this $\epsilon/\delta$-business.

Now limits are an exception handling measure. Given a function $f$ there often are points $a\in{\mathbb R}$, or $a\in\{-\infty,\infty\}$, that barely miss belonging to ${\rm dom}(f)$. Drawing the graph of $f$ we get the impression that when $x$ is near $a$ the function behaves "reasonably" and "tends to some limit" $\eta$. Now we want to express  this observation in a mathematically precise way which then is satisfyable by a real proof. The natural definition is the following: We say that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\eta$ **iff** defining $f(a):=\eta$ would make $f$ continuous there (when $a\in\{-\infty,\infty\}$ special speak is necessary). Expanding this idea we are again back at the $\epsilon/\delta$-business.

Consider as an example the function $f(x):={\sin x\over x}$ which by this expression is defined for all $x\ne0$. In possession of the exact notions (and a precise definition of $\sin$) we can **prove** that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=1$, and then the extended function (called sinc) is defined and continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}$.