# Proving the existence of the limit of a multivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

It is possible to show that the limit $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{|x|+|y|^{\frac{1}{3}}} $$ doesn't exist by approaching the origin in two different ways: along the $x$-axis the limit equals 1, but along the $y$-axis the limit equals 0. 
However if I suppose that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{|x|+|y|^{\frac{1}{3}}}=0$ and use the definition of the limit of a function:
$$ \forall \varepsilon>0 \; \exists \delta : \forall(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus {(0,0)} \; \; |(x,y)|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{|x|+|y|^{\frac{1}{3}}} \right|<\varepsilon $$ I can set $\delta = \varepsilon (|x|+|y|^{\frac{1}{3}})$ and then by definition the limit equals $0$.

Comment: Your $\delta$ depends on $x, y$; if that was allowed every function would be continuous

Comment: If you approach along the x-axis, the limit is not 1. It simply doesn’t exist.

Comment: @WindSoul It should be $1$ for $y=0$. Am’I wrong?

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{|x|}=\frac x{|x|}=\pm 1$.

Comment: @WindSoul Isn't it $\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{|x|}=\frac {|x|}{|x|}= 1$?

Comment: You’re right. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\delta$ can depend from $\varepsilon$ but not from $x$ and $y$, the “game” with the definition of limit is that:

- we fix $\varepsilon$
- then we find $\delta$
- such that $\forall(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus {(0,0)} \; \; |(x,y)|<\delta \implies\,\ldots$

and at the third step $\delta$ is a fixed value depending solely on $\varepsilon$.

Refer also to

- [How to understand the definition of limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2786454/505767)